# Tuple2 mistakenly inferred as Product in recursive Scala function

Tags: scala, type-inference

I've got a function to create combinations from a List of Tuple2[Char,Int].

However when I make a recursive call on it I get a compile error, the Tuple is inferred as a Product.

Why is this and how can I get it to compile?

here's the to code samples

This compiles OK:-

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def combos(a: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
     |     if(a.isEmpty) List(List()) else {
     |       {
     |         for{
     |           x <- 0 to a.length
     |           (char,num) <- a take x
     |           rest = a drop x
     |           less <- num to 1 by -1           
     |         } yield (char,less) :: rest
     |       } toList
     |     }
     |   }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
combos: (a: List[(Char, Int)])List[List[(Char, Int)]]
```

But this recursive one fails.. see the error at the bottom

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def combos(a: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
     |     if(a.isEmpty) List(List()) else {
     |       {
     |         for{
     |           x <- 0 to a.length
     |           (char,num) <- a take x
     |           rest = combos(a drop x)
     |           less <- num to 1 by -1          
     |         } yield (char,less) :: rest
     |       } toList 
     |     }
     |   }
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[List[Product]]
 required: List[List[(Char, Int)]]
             } toList
               ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of rest (the result of combos) is `List[List[(Char,Int)]]` and you're appending `(Char,Int)` so the common inferred type is `Product`.
Maybe you meant `rest <- combos(a drop x)` ?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I'm an idiot! I'd been staring for hours!

Comment: it happens... nothing like a fresh set of eyes :)